# Switch language does not work on ubuntu 14

Tags: language-support, input-language

I am running ubuntu 14 with English and Hebrew enabled but switch language does not work. Mostly going back form Hebrew to English.
After installing  the additional language i set the hot-keys for swithing language ctrl+space for one and func+space for other. 
The problem that after i press ctrl+space i see the 'eng' heb' popup window but the language does not chnage. Only if i use the mouse to select the desired language the keyboard language really charge.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the [related docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html)?

One thing you may want to try is installing the *ibus-m17n* package and relogin. Doing so adds the option *Hebrew (kbd (m17n))* to the list of available input sources, and seems to work fine on my 14.04.

*Edit:*

Thanks for editing the question and clarifying the nature of the problem. I can't tell why **Ctrl+Space** does not work for you; it works for me. What if you try something else, e.g. the default **Super+Space**?